# Check if external file is blocked in a country php

Tags: php, google-maps, block, bing-maps

I'd like to know whether it's a way in php to check whether external file is blocked or not in certain countries.

I need to replace Google map for Bing map in China but functions like get_headers() or file_get_contents() don't do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

In China  you can use  specific google maps url

```
  www.google.cn/maps/
```

and api access

```
  <script src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: the question then is how to check whether it is china or other country

Comment: This is possibile by IP

Comment: I know about IP localisation but I don't want to use external API to slow the website only for that purpose..Another thing it's not accurate.